# How to set date format retrieved from UIDatePicker

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker

I am retrieving date from UIDatePicker ,now i want to convert in to wed, Dec29 12:30pm
format ,
I also want to set that date to UIPickerView's current display date

Comment: post some code here so that we can show you how exactly it is done. And also tell in which format you want to use the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code,its exactly what you want

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[NSTimeZone resetSystemTimeZone];
NSTimeZone *gmtZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmtZone];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"day, MMM HH:mm:ss Z"];

NSDate *dateT = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str1];

NSString *strDateTaken=[appDelegate convertDate:dateT withFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a"];
[dateFormatter release];


- (NSString *)convertDate:(NSDate *)date withFormat:(NSString *)format {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:format];
    NSString *dt = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    [formatter release];
    return dt;
 }
```

str1 is the date fetched in default format...

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks you always do the best :)

Answer (score -3):

if you use jquery:

var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });

More general info available here:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-dateFormat

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

regards

magna