# Setting NSDate from NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I am using XCode 4.2 to develop an iPhone App , I am new to App development

I have the following NSStrings

```
NSString *year;
NSString *month;
NSString *day;
NSString *hour;
NSString *minute;
```

how can I set an `NSDate *date` variable using those

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example:

```
NSString *year   = @"2011";
NSString *month  = @"1";
NSString *day    = @"2";
NSString *hour   = @"3";
NSString *minute = @"3";

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
dateComponents.year   = [year intValue];
dateComponents.month  = [month intValue];
dateComponents.day    = [day intValue];
dateComponents.hour   = [hour intValue];
dateComponents.minute = [minute intValue];

NSDate *date = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
NSLog(@"date: %@", date);
```

NSLog output:

```
date: 2011-01-02 08:03:00 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to create one string that has all the fields necessary to create a date.

That is, something like:

```
NSString * dateString = [NSString dateWithFormat: @"%@-%@-%@ %@:%@", year, month, day, hour, minute];
```

You can then follow [the solutions provided in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353081/nsstring-to-nsdate) or [this other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680228/how-to-turn-a-nsstring-into-nsdate) to come up with your NSDate (and if these solutions don't explain things enough, you can easily do a search -- the question of "how to convert NSStrings to NSDates" comes up quite often here).