# need to set UIDatePickerMode to DateFormat [yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uidatepicker

As far as i saw in iOS `UIDatePickerView` class reference, there are only 4 modes we can set the `Datepickerview` to look like.

```
UIDatePickerModeTime  [ 6 | 53 | PM ].

UIDatePickerModeDate  [ November | 15 | 2007 ].

UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime   [ Wed Nov 15 | 6 | 53 | PM ].

UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer  [ 1 | 53 ].
```

but I need a format like `[ 2007 Nov 15 | 6 | 53 | PM ].`

I am not able to make it. is that by any other means by which it is possible?

please help.

even if it is not possible, suggest some other ways pls..

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720708/setting-uidatepicker-date-with-nsdateformatter

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655199/how-to-set-date-format-retrieved-from-uidatepicker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use directly a [UIPickerView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html) with multiple components instead of a UIDatePicker.

Then you fill the different components in the order you want !

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

You can try using

```
NSDate *date = [[[NSDate alloc] init] retain];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss "];  
date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"your date to be formatted"];
myPicker.date = date;
[date release];
[dateFormatter release];
```

Please modify the above code according to your need.

Comment: no, my problem is to see the pickerview in the format i wish.

Comment: then i guess you will have to go with Haelty answer as there is no other way around.